# UITabBar not showing on initial load

Tags: ios, ios7, swift

I have a problem with getting my UITabBar instantiated when my app is loaded. I have made a subclass of UITabBarController, where I use the method setViewControllers, after instantiating my viewControllers. In them I set custom TabBarItems.. When the app is loaded, my TabBarMenu is just the backgroundcolor i defined, and the first item is selected and showing black. When i click on the TabBarItems, the custom image I have set is showing. After clicking them all my bar works as supposed. Does anyone have an idea of what i am doing wrong?

AppDelegate

```
//Initialize the navagation controller and the bottom bar
var navigationController = UINavigationController()
var bottomBarController = bottomBar()
```

bottomBar

```
class bottomBar: UITabBarController, UITabBarDelegate {

    var buttons: AnyObject[]?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Set the feedController tab, that will show the main feet tab
        var feed: feedController = feedController()

        //Set the inboxController tab, that will let the user sell items
        var inbox: inboxController = inboxController()

        //Set the sellController tab, that will let the user sell items
        var sell: sellController = sellController()

        //Set the profileController tab, that will show info about a user that is logged in
        var profile: profileController = profileController()

        //Set the profileController tab, that will show info about a user that is logged in
        var menu: menuController = menuController()

        //Set the bottomBarController, that will be used as the main navigation bar
        buttons = [feed, inbox, sell, profile, menu]

        self.setViewControllers(buttons, animated: true)

        self.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        self.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 255, green: 255, blue: 255, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```